# GraphQL file uploads and cURL: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 188 (char 187)

Tags: django, graphql, graphql-python

I have a graphql-server that is running at `localhost:3001` I want to send files to a python flask server together with some variables in a `cURL` request. Here is what i'm sending

```bash
curl http://localhost:3001/graphql/  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ConvertDocToPDF($input: ConvertWordDocToPDFInputType!){ convertDocToPDF(input: $input){ success } } ", "variables": { "input" : { "file": null, "saveName": "hello" } ] } }' -F map='{ "0": ["variables.input.file"] }' -F 0=@README.md
```

Surprisingly I'm getting an error which says:

```bash
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 188 (char 187)
[11/Jan/2023 09:38:31] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 500 107387
```

What may be the problem in this request. Any help input will be appreciated

Comment: i don't know JSON, but maybe it's bad format cause one-line code, maybe this works? `curl http://localhost:3001/graphql/  -F operations='{"query":"mutation ConvertDocToPDF($input: ConvertWordDocToPDFInputType!){ convertDocToPDF(input: $input){ success }","variables":{"input":{"file":null,"saveName":"hello"}}}' -F map='{ "0": ["variables.input.file"] }' -F 0=@README.md`

Comment: @whoami Thanks mate for the suggestion i saw the problem. It was suppose to be `curl http://localhost:3001/graphql/  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ConvertDocToPDF($input: ConvertWordDocToPDFInputType!){ convertDocToPDF(input: $input){ success } } ", "variables": { "input" : { "file": null, "saveName": "hello" } } }' -F map='{ "0": ["variables.input.file"] }' -F 0=@README.md`  without `]`

Comment: Yes, one-line can trick our eyes ;)